# setState in reactjs inside success function not setting state

Tags: reactjs, parse-platform

I am using a ParsePlatform as backend storage and reactjs as front end. I am able to get the parse data using Parse.Query but unable to use the returned values as I do not know how to set the state from the successfull fetching of results. I tried like this way inside componentDidMount()

```
import React from 'react'
import Parse from 'parse'
class ConferenceInfo extends React.Component {
    state={
        someData:null
    }
    componentDidMount(){
        this.getConferenceInfo()
    }
    getConferenceInfo(){
        var ConferenceListing = Parse.Object.extend("ConferenceListing");
        var cl = new Parse.Query(ConferenceListing);

        cl.get("8glBIjeRrC", {
            success: function(cl) {
                // The object was retrieved successfully.
                alert(cl.get("someData")) //it works
                //this.setState({someData:cl.get("someData")}) not working              
            },
            error: function(object, error) {
                // The object was not retrieved successfully.
                // error is a Parse.Error with an error code and message.
            }
        });
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                {this.state.someData} //no result
            </div>
        )
    }
}
export default ConferenceInfo
```

Comment: it's binding issue write it like this: `success: (cl) => {this.setState({....})` it should work.

Comment: Thank you for the comment, I have no idea but this also does not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because `this` is not in the same scope. You are calling it inside `success` property, function callback.

To get it working we need to `bind` `this`.

First Create constructor method.

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  // Our new bind method ref
  this.change = this.change.bind(this);
}
```

Then add new method `change`

```
change(obj) {
  this.setState(obj);
}
```

Finally your `success` callback

```
success: function(cl) {
  // ...
  this.change({ someData: cl.get("someData") })           
},
```

Comment: @user109640 Glad I could help you. Don't forget to move your `this.state = {}` inside constructor.

Comment: State in constructor is not a necessity, With the latest plugins for babel, you can specify state even without the constructor

Comment: @loelsonk yes i had already declared the state. thank you nonce again. Shubham thank you too

Comment: @loelsonk For me, change(obj) method is not getting called, after success function callback